# Processing not executing draw properly when using sound

Tags: audio, arduino, processing

So I have a Processing file that receives incoming data from two Arduino sensors, and Processing saves the sensor value in two ints. Processing is supposed to print the data into the console, which it does, but I also have an if statement that prints a line to the console and changes the audio volumes, but the if statement is not being run. I put two texts on the canvas, and those are also not appearing. When I remove the sound related code, it perfectly runs the code, it prints the string to the console when the values are above 10, and the text appears on the canvas. I'm pretty new to coding and I have no idea what causes this and I have not been able to figure out what's wrong after hours of testing and searching the internet.

It only returns:

```
jun. 11, 2023 11:48:23 P.M. com.jsyn.devices.javasound.JavaSoundAudioDevice <init>
INFO: JSyn: default output latency set to 80 msec for Windows 10

0,0

0,0

0,0
```

etc.

Processing code;

```
import processing.sound.*;
import processing.serial.*;          

Serial myPort;

String val;

int datanum = 0;

int val1;
int val2;

AudioSample glitched;
AudioSample music;
AudioSample enabled;

void setup() {  
  size(400, 400);
  frameRate(30);
  
  String portName = Serial.list()[0];
  myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600);
  myPort.bufferUntil('\n');
  
  glitched = new SoundFile(this, "glitchedNew.mp3");
  glitched.loop();
  glitched.amp(1);
  music = new SoundFile(this, "music.mp3");
  music.loop();
  music.amp(0);
  enabled = new SoundFile(this, "enabled.mp3");
}

void draw() {
  rect(120, 80, 220, 220);
  
  if (val1 > 10 && val2 > 10) {
     glitched.amp(0);
     music.amp(1);
     println("Sound 1 now playing");
  } else {
     glitched.amp(1);
     music.amp(0);
  }
  
  text(val1, 20, 20);
  text(val2, 20, 60);  
}

void serialEvent(Serial myPort) {  
  val = myPort.readStringUntil('\n'); 
  if (val != null) {
     val = trim(val);
     int[] vals = int(splitTokens(val, ","));
    
     if(vals.length >= datanum) {
        val1 = vals[0];
        val2 = vals[1];
      
        print(val1);
        print(",");
        print(val2);
        println();
    }
  }  
}
```

Arduino code:

```
const int sensorPin1 = A0;
const int sensorPin2 = A1;

int val;

void setup() {

  pinMode(sensorPin1, INPUT);
  pinMode(sensorPin2, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {

  int sensorVal1 = analogRead(sensorPin1);
  int sensorVal2 = analogRead(sensorPin2);

  Serial.print(sensorVal1);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(sensorVal2);
  Serial.println();

}
```

I have tried to put my code into one void as that was the only possible problem I could find online, but that didn't have any effect. It should run perfectly fine, like it does without the sound, but it just doesn't, so I hope someone here is able to help me.

Comment: I think I've had this type of problem before, and the problem wasn't my code. It was the fact that I was using `print` in _both_ Arduino and Processing. Something about you have to choose between one since they are both using the same COM port. When two programs use the same COM port, they end up fighting over it and one program wins, even though you want both to use it at the same time. I suggest redirecting your research to something along those lines. Lmk if you need further help/can't find anything about it.

Comment: In my experience serialEvent() doesn't like to do very much except parse data.  Try removing the if(){...} construct and evaluating the array elsewhere.